# how to invoke method from imported module in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Just trying to understand basic concept of typescript class instance i have imported the test module now i tried to call that method on class but its not printing anything. Any help will be appreciated ?

main.ts

```
 export class Testbase {
      public test(arg: string) {
        return arg;
      }

    }
```

instance.ts

```
        import {Testbase} from "./main";

        export class CallBack {
          private testClass: Testbase;
          private desc: string = "testing typesceript";
          constructor() {
            this.testClass = new Testbase();
            this.testClass.test(this.desc);
            console.log('test');
          }
           public printStr(str:string) {
             this.testClass.test(this.desc);
           }

        }
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of CallBack as well only then constructor will be called.

Comment: can you provide any example please

Comment: const obj = CallBack();
obj.printStr('Hello world);